# Open text file using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to set an 'EditText' to the contents of a simple txt file. After looking at the developer page I stumbled across some code that gets a photo. I edited to what I thought would suit my needs but it doesn't work:

```
private void importText(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("text/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String textContent = data.getDataString();
        mEditText.setText(textContent);
    }
}
```

What this does is it puts the string name of what appears to be the files location in the `EditText` not the contents of it. My app right now only supports API 19 so I thought I would be able to use this as a feature. Is this function possible using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or do I need to do something else?

Comment: If all you want to do is display the contents of a text file, why don't you just open / read that file yourself and set the text of the `EditText` yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Use following method to read data  :

```
 public static String readTextFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (InputStream inputStream =
                 context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream)))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

and get uri from given intent in onActivityResult method :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       Uri uri = data.getData();
       String myText = readTextFromUri(yourContext , uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do I use instead of ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to select a file and get the actual path? I have code to read the file using FileInputStream

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve an Input Stream from the Uri as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html). (Section "Get an Input Stream").

Comment: private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (InputStream inputStream =
                     getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream)))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }